# Cantilever cable adjustment device

Tags: brakes, cyclocross

I'm about to build up a frame (Motobecane Fantom CX) with cantilevers and drop bars. I plan to use my old Campy 9-speed levers. Obviously, those levers don't have any way of adjusting the cable length - so I'll have to add some way to adjust it. I know I can buy a front cable hanger with an adjusting barrel, so that takes care of the front. It's the rear that I can't figure out: this frame already has a cable stop for the rear brake, so I don't think I even have the option of installing one of those adjustable hangers on the seat bolt. I think what I need is some sort of adjusting barrel that can fit into the existing cable stop - does such a thing exist? If not, how can I make one?

[image]

Comment: I wonder if it's worth editing the subject to be a little more specific. "Cantilever brake adjusters for use with drop bars?" or something would make the question/answers easier to find.

Comment: @moz - OK, done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get in-line cable housing adjusters.

<strike>A pair is listed on http://www.sheldonbrown.com/harris/cable-hardware-brake.html, part CAH32. I think those are made by jagwire, and they should be available at virtually any bike shop.</strike>

edit: those inline adjusters are for derailleur cables only. Use this http://harriscyclery.net/product/qbp-mickey-cable-barrel-adjuster-1061.htm for brake cables. It goes in the cable stop. Being a QBP product, you should also be able to obtain those at virtually any local bike shop.

Answer (score 2):

Try haunting established bike shops for their "old parts" boxes... Most have 'em....

I'm sure I have seen the sort of device you would need; essentially an adjusting barrel with a knurled ring around the outside that would allow the threaded portion to just slide into the frame boss.
If not the dedicated part, perhaps you could incorporate the adjuster mechanism for a rear DR?  They would be about the right size.

Good luck with the cantis, I know some folks still like 'em, but I was glad to wave by-by.  The pads did last a long time....

Comment: Well, I wanted a frame for road riding that would allow me to run fatter tires. And I wanted to keep my old wheels and brake levers, so cantis were the only choice.

Comment: This is the correct answer and the part is correct for the era. The barrel adjuster from old 'Weinmann' style sidepulls can be used too.

Answer (score 0):

I put  [Surly Cable Hangers](http://surlybikes.com/parts/cable_hanger) on all my bikes with canti brakes. They have an adjustable barrel to alter the cable tension before the straddle cable hanger.